# Combine CSV files

Tags: linux, perl, programming-languages

What's the best way to combine two csv files and append the results to the same line in perl?

For example, one CSV file looks like

```
1234,user1,server
4323,user2,server
532,user3,server
```

The second looks like

```
user1,owner
user2,owner
user3,owner1
```

The result I want it to look like is

```
1234,user1,server,owner
4323,user2,server,owner
532,user3,server,owner1
```

The users are not in order so I'll need to search the first csv file which I've stored in an array to see which users match then apply the owner to the end of the line.

So far I've read in both files into arrays and then I get lost

I would post the code but it's part of a much larger script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds most suited for a hash. First read the one file into a hash, then add the other. Might add warnings for values that exist in one file but not the other.

Something like:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV;
use autodie;

my %data;
my $file1 = "user.csv";
my $file2 = "user2.csv";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } );

open my $fh, '<', $file1;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    my ($num, $user, $server) = @$row;
    $data{$user} = { 'num' => $num, 'server' => $server };
}

open $fh, '<', $file2;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    my ($user, $owner) = @$row;
    if (not defined $data{$user}) {
         # warning? something else appropriate
    } else {
         $data{$user}{'owner'} = $owner;
    }
}

for my $user (keys %data) {
    print join(',', $data{$user}{'num'}, $user, $data{$user}{'server'}, 
         $data{$user}{'owner'}), "\n";
}
```

Edit: As recommended in comments and other answers, I changed the method of extracting the data to using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) instead of `split`. I'm not too familiar with the module, but it seems to be working in my testing.

Comment: +1, but I'd also use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) instead of `split`.

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of this answer. Since the rest of the script (that does much more work) was already in perl the other answer written in bash wouldn't work. Thanks

Comment: @zoite I've written an updated version using Text::CSV as recommended in the comments.

Comment: `split` is fine if you're certain the CSV files will never use any form of quoting or escaping (i.e. fields can never contain commas or newlines).  Otherwise, you want Text::CSV to handle the special cases correctly.

Comment: @cjm Good to know. Might be safest to use it anyway, in case the data changes later on.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a direct application for the `join` command (tied with `sort`).  This assumes that the data is as simple as shown - no commas embedded in strings or anything nasty.

```
sort -t, -k 2 file1 > file1.sorted
sort -t, -k 1 file2 > file2.sorted
join -t, -1 2 -2 1 file1.sorted file2.sorted
```

With `bash`, you could do it all on one line.

If you really want to do it in Perl, then you need to use a hash keyed by the user column, potentially with an array of entries per hash key.  You then iterate through the keys of one of the hashes, pulling the matching values from the other and printing the data.  If you're in Perl, you can use the Text::CSV module to get accurate CSV splitting.

Comment: Will this work if there's a different number of users in the files?

Comment: @TLP: yes - it is quite happy if there are 16 different users in one file and 37 in the other (and only 12 of them are in common).  The common ones will be printed; the others ignored unless you tweak the options to `join`.  Further, if there are 3 entries in File1 for user23 and 4 in File2, you will see a dozen rows output, rather like you would in a relational database with a join.  You can join on more than one column, too, if that's appropriate.  The `join` command is powerful but fussy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1st has 2 commas, and the 2nd only one, you will get all lines of the 1st file, but only the matching ones of the 2nd:

```
my %content;
while( <$file1> ) {
    chomp;
    /,(.+),/;
    $content{$1} = "$_,";
}
while( <$file2> ) {
    chomp;
    /(.+),(.+)/;
    $content{$1} .= $2;
}
print "$content{$_}\n" for sort keys %content;
```

Answer (score 0):

import csv

files=['h21.csv', 'h20.csv','h22.csv']
lineCount=0

for file in files:
    with open(file,'r') as f1:
        csv_reader=csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
        with open('testout1.csv','a' ,newline='') as f2:
            csv_writer=csv.writer(f2,delimiter=',')
            if lineCount==0:
                csv_writer.writerow(["filename","sno","name","age"])
                lineCount += 1

```
        next(csv_reader,None)
        for row in csv_reader:
            data=[file]+row
            csv_writer.writerow(data)
```